# Why preferredStatusBarStyle doesn't change the style of the status bar?

Tags: ios

I put `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` in Info.plist; so that, I can alter the status bar appearance per controller. If I want to hide status bar in any controller, it works but when it comes to changing the status bar text to light content:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
}
```

This just doesn't change the value. I tried to add

```
self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate();
```

to `viewDidLoad` but also got no luck.

What am I doing wrong? The Top Controller is Navigation Controller that is added by embedding the "main top controller" in navigation controller using the interface builder.

Comment: Have you tried self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent ?

Comment: Yes it worked but I still don't get why preferred status bar didn't work. Is it because navigation bar is overriding it's values?